# How to reload the table content after deleting one record in ajax on success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code : 
My code is working, but my success function of ajax is not working I want to show the updated record after deleting the row, without refreshing the page.
I have checked my answers here on StackOverflow, but my problem is not solving, please help.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<table border="1">
    <?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql ="SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){

    echo '<tr><td>'.$row->fname.'</td><td>'.$row->lname.'</td>'.'

    <a href="#" id="'.$row->id.'" class="trash" >
   de
    </a>

    '.'</td></tr>';
    }

?>
  </table>

</body>
 <script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.trash',function(){
        var del_id= $(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'del.php',
            data:{'del_id':del_id},
            success: function(data){
                 if(data=="YES"){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                 }else{
                        alert("can't delete the row")
                 }
                 }
             }

            });
        });
});</script>
</html>
```

and **del.php** file is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test');
$music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
//echo $music_number;
$qry = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id ='$music_number'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
if(isset($result)) {
   echo "YES";
} else {
   echo "NO";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error and your problem?

Comment: Sir updated record is not showing.

Comment: You have one `}` to many in your code, after the `alert`-statement. A copy-paste error? Or do you have this error in your code too? Sidenote: you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions anymore, they are deprecated and removed in PHP7. Sidenote 2: your code is vulnarable to a SQL-injection attack in your `DELETE`-statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.trash').click(function(){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');  // **add this
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'del.php',
                data: {
                    'del_id': del_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == "YES") {
                        tr.fadeOut(1000, function(){ // **add this
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("can't delete the row")
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The `closest` method returns  the first ancestor of the selected element.
https://api.jquery.com/closest/